# Creating simulated items sold at a store into a hash

Tags: ruby, hash-map

I am writing code that creates a hash for a store that has an item, price, and sku.  The hash is inserted into an array.  I also create another hash based on the sku that holds the amount of inventory for that item.  I am new to Ruby and am looking for ways to improve my code.

```
 class SimStore
      def item_info
        random = Random.new
        price = random.rand(1.00 ... 75.00).round(2)
        item = 1.times.map { RandomWord.nouns.next }
        sku_random = Random.new
        sku = sku_random.rand(1000 ... 1000000)
        sum_store_hash = {:item => item, :price => price, :sku => sku}
      end


  def stock array_items_stock
    stock_hash = {}
    array_items_stock.each do |inventory|
       random = Random.new
       quantity = random.rand(10 ... 100)
       stock_hash[inventory[:sku]] = quantity
     end
    stock_hash
  end
end

items = 15;
array_items = []
hash_inventory = []
while items > 0
  items = items - 1
  sim_store = SimStore.new
  items_hash = sim_store.item_info
  array_items.push(items_hash)
end

hash_inventory = sim_store.stock array_items
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SimStore` class doesn't seem to do much except create a hash and create an item. These seem like separate concerns

You really could use an `Item` class with a static method for stubbing out an Item.

First, let's start with an "Item" class:

```
class Item
  attr_accessor :price, :name, :sku, :quantity

  def initialize(name, sku, price, quantity)
    self.name = name
    self.sku = sku
    self.price = price
    self.quantity = quantity
  end

  def self.stub
    price = Random.new.rand(1.00 ... 75.00).round(2)
    name = 1.times.map { RandomWord.nouns.next }
    sku = Random.new.rand(1000 ... 1000000)
    quantity = Random.new.rand(10 ... 100)

    self.new name, sku, price, quantity
  end

  def to_h
    { name: name, price: price, sku: sku, quantity: quantity }
  end
end
```

It has a `price`, `name` and `sku` that is a getter and setter. A static, or class level method called `Item.stub` generates a fake item based on the code you are using. Lastly, it has a `to_hash` method for converting the `Item` into a `Hash`.

Now we can take one step back and think about your `SimStore`, which at this point doesn't simulate anything so we can rename it to `Store`:

```
class Store
  def items
    @items ||= []
  end

  def self.stub(number_of_items)
    store = self.new

    number_of_items.times do |i|
      store.items << Item.stub
    end

    store
  end

  def to_h
    items.map { |item| item.to_hash }
  end

  def sku_hash
    # For Ruby < 2.1
    array = items.map { |item| [item.sku, item.quantity] }
    Hash[array]

    # For Ruby >= 2.1
    items.map { |item| [item.sku, item.quantity] }.to_h
  end
end
```

It has an array of Items and a `to_hash` method that converts the entire store into a Hash. Additionally, it also has a class method called `stub`, which accepts the number of items that should be stubbed out.

You wanted to convert the items into a Hash of SKUs for the keys, and quantities for the values, so explicitly creating a `sku_hash` method seems to be more appropriate.

And to use it:

```
store = Store.stub 15
store_hash = store.to_hash # => [{name: '...', sku: 123, price: 23.99}, ...]
sku_hash = stsore.sku_hash # => { 'sku1' => 2, 'sku2' => 55 }
```

By separating the `Item` from the `Store` and adding class methods to stub items and entire stores, you get two classes that can actually be used in a real context, but also can be used just for playing around.

Comment: You may use `Enumerable#map`

Comment: @tokland: Done and done. I don't get to write much Ruby these days, so posting on Code Review is the only way I can keep up. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great. You can also write `number_of_items.times.map` :)

Comment: @tokland: True, but `Store#items` is only a getter, and I'm modifying that `Array` object instead of assigning a whole different object to it.

Comment: Oh, you are right!

Comment: +1 Great answer. The original `stock` creates a SKU-to-quantity hash. So `Store#to_hash` should be `items.map { | item| [ item.sku, item.quantity ] }.to_h` (untested). Also rename `to_hash` to `to_h` in both classes.

Comment: @Spike: In Ruby 1.9.3 there is no `to_h` method on the Array object, which was introduced in v2.1. Updated my answer with your suggestions. I missed the fact that the Hash was supposed to be sku => quantity. Thanks!

Comment: Greg: whenever using old Ruby versions, the gem `backports` is very useful.